# What are these libraries included with Excel's VBA editor? Is there any formal documentation on how use them all?

Tags: excel, vba

When you open Excel's VBA editor and go to Tools > References, you get prompted with a menu that looks [this](https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-reference-libraries-in-excel-workbook/). From what I can tell these are all libraries that Windows come with Windows, some of which are usable in Excel (please, correct me if I am wrong).

Some Examples taken at random:

- CertEnroll 1.0 Type Library
- azroles 1.0 Type Library
- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- scripto 1.0 Type Library

What are these exactly? Is there any formal documentation on these individual libraries and how to use them? Or at the very least is there a resource that describes what they are used for?

Comment: These are libraries that were installed by either Windows or **any other software**. The documentation of each has to be searched for on goolge (or any other search engine). There is no collected documentation for all the software that exists word wide. Since anyone in the world can write such a library (even you, if you  learn how to) you can imagine that what you ask for cannot exist. • Actually if you don't know them you probably don't need them anyway.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk